# Import graphql schema from parent module in spring boot

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, netflix-dgs, graphql-spring-boot

I am trying to import my schema definition files from a parent module which is imported in maven. The schema files exist under resources in my parent jar file, is there a way to import those schema files in my child project? I can copy the files from the parent jar using the maven plugin but that doesn't seem right, is there another way?
here is graphqlconfig file in parent project

```
{
  "projects": {
    "a": {
      "includes": [
        "schema-a/**"
      ]
    },
    "b": {
      "includes": [
        "schema-b/**"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

how do I import and refer to these schema files in my child project? I am using netflix dgs with spring boot in case that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

dgs:
graphql:
schema-locations: classpath*:schema/**/*.graphqls fixes the issue